# Learning Russian - Can someone explain what that means?

Tags: значения, транслитерация

I am learning Russian and I've stumbled upon this piece of text.

I can't quite figure out what it says...

> Однажды я гулял по лесу, вижу колодец. Подхожу к нему, захожу в лифт,
>   сажусь на велосипед, завожу мотоцикл, тут Бац, ко мне кондуктор
>   подходит, и говорит: ''Дядя, уступи место'' А я говорю что не курю.
>   Так этот ребенок как начнет плакать! Но я не растерялся, и как дал ему
>   по роже, а он хватается за коленку и кричит: ''Моя спина! Моя спина!
>   '' А я думаю, может он совсем дибил? Выхожу я из этой электрички,
>   смотрю, маршрутка стоит. Ну подхожу и говорю: ''винстон синий и водки
>   0,5'' Ну она мне и дает bond и пиво, я беру эту приму и самогон, и
>   убегаю от этих мусоров! Так эти пожарники меня на скорой догнали!
>   Догнали и говорят: ''Вы сдачу забыли! '' Ну я беру килограмм яблок, и
>   иду на базар торговать! Приношу, успел выложить эти бананы, тут же
>   бабка подбегает, и скупает у меня все персики, и говорит чтобы все
>   сложил в кулечек! А я думаю, что она совсем дура, как я ей 20 арбузов
>   в сумку положу?! Взял я деньги и пошел домой! Больше я в лес не
>   ходил... и грибы не трогал. Лучше в компьютер пойду поиграю!

It seems like a story of a guy, but I really can't quite understand it, and the translation software doesn't make sense as well.

Comment: All sentences are not directly related to each other and not a real story, each next  one has a change of an object noun to a different one, kind of. Do you have a problem with understanding or translation some of them or a specific question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The text is complete nonsense, it can serve as a good example of [schizophasia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schizophasia). Obviously the text is intended to sound funny.

Comment: Oh. So that's what it was :) And here I thought my Russian is so bad that I couldn't even understand it.

Comment: @JohnytheB - The story begins in the forest, and in the end the guy says he never went to the forest any more and didn't have any more mushrooms, so it's probably the guy's story of his hallucination.

Answer (score 15):

The giveaway is the sentence before the last:

```
 Больше я в лес не ходил... и грибы не трогал
```

It hints that the person describing this nonsense has eaten some mushrooms in the woods and got hallucinated a bit.